# Is It Possible to Get User Info of Everyone Who Uses My App

Tags: php, facebook, registration, facebook-apps, userinfo

If we didn't capture the information at signup is there a way to see who our users are?

Or if I have partial info on a user can I get more info they agreed to share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When user signs up in your website via facebook,he gives you pemission to access basic info(and all other info for which you took pemission).

Facebook is all about pemissions.You ask the user to grant permission to access user data.In other words,You can access any data for which you have permission.

You can access the basic info like User name,Location,etc.(Which come under basic info) at any time(even if you didn't capture the information at signup ) with a valid access token and a user reference like user ID.

You can get the offline_access permission to publish or get user data even when user is offline.

Comment: I accessed name, location, email address but not userid. Ideally I'd like to get their profile pictures now after the fact. Is that possible?

Comment: userid is something that you should always capture when user first comes to ur website.What mwthod are you using bdw.Gaph api/Javascript..??

Answer (score 1):

You have to get specific extended permissions with a access token. So basically, you can get more info if they agree to share.

Answer (score 0):

You would have needed to have recorded the user id in order to retrieve the picture easily as there is no way to get a list of users that have approved your app.  One workaround that will cover a majority of your users is to use the Facebook Graph API to search for users based on the email that you say you recorded.  You could do something like:

[https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=zuck@fb.com&type=user&access_token=...](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=search?q=zuck@fb.com&type=user)